# Can't change anything under 'More Info' for page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am trying to change things like **Current Location** and **Genre** under the section *More Info*. This section is last in the *About* tab. My page has the category **Musician/Band** (not sure if that makes a difference).

Before any information is entered, a link appears allowing you to add that information. Once added, however, it just displays as text. There is no **Edit** or **Change** link to update that information later on.

I have checked using both Mobile and Desktop versions. I have navigated the page settings where page information is found as well as on the page directly. This is odd. I recall updating my current location as early as three months ago.

Anybody else experience this phenomenon?